# Can Visual Studio Code work with mixed-language, .NET Core solutions?

Tags: c#, f#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Is there a simple fix for the following? Or is this a bug in VSCode and/or the language-specific extensions?

I created two projects and a solution like this:

```
dotnet new library -lang F# -o .\ClassLibrary
dotnet new console -lang C# -o .\MainProgram
dotnet new sln
dotnet sln add .\ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.fsproj
dotnet sln add .\MainProgram\MainProgram.csproj
```

I added a project reference to the ClassLibrary from within the MainProgram.

```
dotnet add reference ..\ClassLibrary\ClassLibrary.fsproj
```

I updated the Program.cs to call the ClassLibrary.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassLibrary.Say.hello("world.");
}
```

I can restore, build, and run the program successfully.

```
dotnet restore
dotnet run -p .\MainProgram\MainProgram.csproj
```

**The problem is when I open the solution folder in Visual Studio Code.**

- When I open Program.cs, the editor red-underlines the F# library types as being missing.
- When I open Library.fs, the editor red-underlines pretty much everything. Interestingly, the errors are from a C# compiler, not an F# compiler.
- Ctrl-Shift-B builds the projects with 0 Warning(s) and 0 Error(s).
- VSCode's Problems windows displays 12 compiler errors.

[image]

[image]

I have also tried opening the project folders separately.

- If I open VS Code in the F# library project, Intellisense works.
- If I open VS Code in the C# console project, the editor still does not recognize the types from F# library.

**Update**

I have VS Code version 1.15.1, with five extensions installed.

1. C#, 1.12.1
2. Ionide-fsharp, 2.33.0
3. Language PL/SQL, 1.0.4
4. Mono Debug, 0.15.7
5. XML Tools, 1.9.2

Comment: Since you didn't mention it in your question, I should probably ask: do you have the Ionide-fsharp extension installed?

Comment: @rmunn Yes, if I open VS Code in the F# library project, the Ionide-fsharp extension seems to work great.

Comment: Then my best guess is that the Omnisharp extension hasn't been designed to deal with mixed-language projects. I have no relevant experience as I've only written single-language F# projects so far, so I can't give you an actual answer.

Comment: I wonder if Intellisense would work properly if the projects were opened as a "Multi Root Workspace." Currently, that feature is only available in the Insider version. I am not using the Insider version of VS Code, so I cannot test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we just need to wait for [this fix](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/371).

And, if you have Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 installed, update to [the latest version and F# compiler workload](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2075).